# JSON string decoding error

Tags: python, urllib2, json

I am calling the URL :

```
http://code.google.com/feeds/issues/p/chromium/issues/full/291?alt=json
```

using urllib2 and decoding using the json module

```
url = "http://code.google.com/feeds/issues/p/chromium/issues/full/291?alt=json"
request = urllib2.Request(query)
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
issue_report = json.loads(response.read())
```

I run into the following error :

```
ValueError: Invalid control character at: line 1 column 1120 (char 1120)
```

I tried checking the header and I got the following :

```
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Expires: Sun, 03 Jul 2011 17:38:38 GMT
Date: Sun, 03 Jul 2011 17:38:38 GMT
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-transform
Vary: Accept, X-GData-Authorization, GData-Version
GData-Version: 1.0
ETag: W/"CUEGQX47eCl7ImA9WxJaFEw."
Last-Modified: Tue, 04 Aug 2009 19:20:20 GMT
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Server: GSE
Connection: close
```

I also tried adding an encoding parameter as follows :

```
issue_report = json.loads(response.read() , encoding = 'UTF-8')
```

I still run into the same error.

Comment: It looks like that what you get is not a valid json encoded string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The feed has raw data from a JPEG in it at that point; the JSON is malformed, so it's not your fault. Report a bug to Google.

Comment: Oh! I suspect people have run into such issues earlier too. http://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=942

Answer (score 2):

You could consider using [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/) instead, since the JSON is malformed. It's XPath support makes working with XML pretty straight-forward:

```
import lxml.etree
url = 'http://code.google.com/feeds/issues/p/chromium/issues/full/291'
doc = lxml.etree.parse(url)
ns = {'issues': 'http://schemas.google.com/projecthosting/issues/2009'}
issues = doc.xpath('//issues:*', namespaces=ns)
```

Fairly easy to manipulate elements, for instance to strip namespace from tags, convert to dict:

```
>>> dict((x.tag[len(ns['issues'])+2:], x.text) for x in issues)
<<<    
{'closedDate': '2009-08-04T19:20:20.000Z',
 'id': '291',
 'label': 'Area-BrowserUI',
 'stars': '13',
 'state': 'closed',
 'status': 'Verified'}
```

Comment: Thanks but I always prefer JSON objects since they are very easily converted into dictionaries.

Comment: I prefer JSON too, but sometimes you don't have a choice.